# Characters in string getting replaced when echoed

Tags: linux, bash, unix, command-line-interface, openstack

I am writing a simple script to collect 2 IP addresses. I am using the open stack client to gather the allocation pool of a provider network. I used awk to gather the 2 IP addresses (start and end) and put them into 2 variables. When I echo the 2 variables alone they print out how I expect. However, if I try to echo something after the variable, it seems to replace the first few characters of the IP address.

It hard to explain, but if you refer to the output it should make more sense. If you look at my script below, I just put the string "hello" after the variable in each echo statement for demonstrative purposes.

```
#!/bin/bash
NETWORK=$1

#just gets the allocation pool IP addresses from openstack
ALLOCATION_POOLS=$(openstack subnet show $NETWORK --insecure|grep -w "allocation_pools"|awk -F " " '{print $4}')

POOL_START=$(awk -F "-" '{print $1}' <<< "$ALLOCATION_POOLS")
echo $POOL_START"hello"
POOL_END=$(awk -F "-" '{print $2}' <<< "$ALLOCATION_POOLS")
echo $POOL_END"hello"
```

Here is the output:

```
hello.146.87
hello.146.126
```

If I did not put "hello" in the echo statement, the output looks more like this:

```
10.28.146.87
10.28.146.126
```

Another thing I did was tested the length of the strings, and the length was larger then the number of characters in the ip address. I believe that there is some strange character after the IP addresses that is causing this. If that is the case, how can I remove it?

Comment: You are getting `\r` at the end of your variables

Comment: Hi i have just tested your script on linux box and i found string "hello" on 7 & 9 line  . can you please remove it . kindly post output of 

ALLOCATION_POOLS=$(openstack subnet show $NETWORK --insecure|grep -w "allocation_pools"|awk -F " " '{print $4}')